# How can I adjust bokeh x axis ticker in intervals

Tags: python, plot, graph, bokeh

How can I see that whole number on the x- axis such as 704,705,706 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`SingleIntervalTicker`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html#bokeh.models.tickers.SingleIntervalTicker)

```
p.xaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=1)
```

Comment: that is an amazing solution! I just want to take this chance to say thank you for all your answers in the other bokeh question. It is really making a whole lot of difference. Keep it up (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the x axis column to the x.axis.ticker in bokeh

```
p.xaxis.ticker = df['x']
```

[image]

Comment: That will create a `FixedTicker` which is another option, but it will not generate ticks outside the exact ones in `df['x']`. That might be OK for your use case if no zoom is enabled.